# Vue в data использовать getter текущего объекта

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, getter

Допустим у нас есть такой код

```
data() {
 return {
  payinRange: window.__DATA__.payinRange,
  payinStruct: window.__DATA__.payinStruct
 }
}
```

2 раза не очень хочется обращаться к глобальному объекту, по этому я хотел использовать getter и сделать например так:

```
DATA: window.__DATA__,
get payinRange () { this.DATA.payinRange },
get payinStruct () { this.DATA.payinStruct },
```

но тогда переопределяется контекст вызова ф-ции и this.DATA уже undefined, есть ли способ присвоить значения в data не обращаясь 2 раза к глобальной переменной?

Answer (score -1):

Нужно инициализировать данные [в хуках жизненного цикла Vue](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B0), если начальных значений нет можно указать `null` или пустой строкой '':

```
// es6 
...
data() {
  return {
    payinRange: null,
    payinStruct: null
  }
}, 
created() {
  // let data = ... // ? но зачем
  // const DATA = window.__DATA__; // ? но зачем

  // Лучше добавить валидацию и предупреждения об ошибках
  // window.__DATA__ = window.__DATA__ || {}
  // this.payinRange = window.__DATA__.payinRange || <default value>

  this.payinRange = window.__DATA__.payinRange 
  this.payinStruct = window.__DATA__.payinStruct
},
...
```

> На заметку: Объект присваивается и копируется «по ссылке». В переменной хранится не сам объект, а адрес в памяти.

Используйте [Vuex для управления состоянием приложения](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/state.html).